# Why is my openlayers map not showing?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to create a plunker to find out a solution when adding projection list in Openlayers. But when I add a sample map, it's not showing the map and there is no error in the console either.

```
var olview = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: olview
});
```

[Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wfheTcVKcXHZZ0R5FaYJ?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next&preview)

Comment: You need to move the script.js from the head to the body after the map div

Comment: What was offered by @Mike does make sense

Comment: its working fine when i changed script reference to body, but when I put debugger in script file , I can access Ol.Map objects , why still not working if the script is inside head tag ?

Comment: @AhammadaliPK your script file makes references to the `map div`, so this div must be created before the script can work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `<script>` tags containing your .js file into `<body>` the map will show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.js"> 

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map1"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file.

```
.map {
height: 550px;
width: 100%;
```

}

You have to include the styling in openlayers. This will display the map and obviously, change the style to your liking.